# unexpected behavior using two modals in one html file with Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddled/1hgu6876/) I have two modals sign in & sign up and they're supposed to run 
by clicking corresponding links in the nav, each one of them can work 
fine individually, the second I uncomment the second modal markup only 
one of them works, usually the first in precedence inside html file. the
 code is as follows:

what happens when I click on sign in, it opens the first modal 
without issues, then I close it, and click on sign up button, nothing 
happens at all. Clicking on sign in once again displays the new element 
loaded with the sign up modal content. which is quite strange

```
<div class="menu-group-right condense">
<ul class="icon-left primary menu-bar condense">
    <li><a href="#" zf-open="loginModal"><img zf-iconic="" 

icon="Account" size="small" class="iconic-color-primary">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" zf-open="signupModal"><img zf-iconic="" icon="Circle-check" size="small" class="iconic-color-primary">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>



<div zf-modal="" id="loginModal" class="collapse">
  <div class="grid-block vertical">
    <div class="primary title-bar">
      <div class="center title">Sign In</div>
        <span zf-close="" class="right"><a><img zf-iconic="" icon="Circle-x" size="small" class="iconic-color-primary">Close</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-content padding" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
              <form>
              <div class="grid-block">
                <div class="small-12 medium-6 grid-content">

                  <label>Username</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" />                  
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" />
            </form>
        <input class"button" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div zf-modal="" id="signupModal" class="collapse">
  <div class="grid-block vertical">
    <div class="primary title-bar">
      <div class="center title">Sign Up</div>
        <span zf-close="" class="right"><a><img zf-iconic=""  icon="Circle-x" size="small" class="iconic-color-primary">Close</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-content padding" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
            <form>
              <div class="grid-block">
                <div class="small-12 medium-6 grid-content">
                  <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" />

                  <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
                  <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" />
                  <label>Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" />
            </form>
        <input class"button" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
        </div>
  </div>
</div>enter code here
```

Comment: Please show us an example site or create a Fiddle so we can see the error in action.

Comment: I created a fiddle, and the result shows both modals. I'm not sure if this captures the behavior I'm dealing with, but there it is anyway https://jsfiddle.net/fiddled/1hgu6876/